# How do I politely say "Stay out of my office" to people other than my management?

Tags: work-environment

Other employees keep coming in my office once I'm gone for the day. I want to leave a note telling them not to be in my office while I'm not there but I don't want to seem nasty about it.

Comment: What are they doing in your office?  Do they need stuff that only you have?  Are you a team lead or something that they are leaving stuff for you that they are working on?  Or do they just go hang out in there and do random things when you're gone?

Comment: Yeah, before we can give advice for how to keep them out, it will help to know why they are coming in.

Comment: i am a supervisor in housekeeping there isn't anything that they would have to get they have papers to turn in but that can be put under the door i feel as if the housemen are chilling out when management isn't here

Comment: You could put a sign on the door when you are away. "PLEASE LEAVE PAPERS UNDER DOOR" or something similar.

Comment: How about a lock on the door that only you and management have a key to?

Comment: The lock that @mikeazo suggested, plus a bin beside the door to turn papers in.  I'm never comfortable "sliding something under the door."  That seems disrespectful both to the person in the office and to the customers whose content is in the paperwork.

Comment: Other than they may suspect your negative assumption, "the housemen are chilling out when management isn't here" would they have any reason to interpret a simple request to Please Do Not Use Office as nasty? We need to know more about your relationship.

Comment: @JeffO i am a supervisor, their supervisor but at the same time i didn't want to come on to them as if i saying Don't go in my damn office that's why I'm asking of a better way to say it instead of coming as the ass hole of a boss for the others that don't go in the office in that way

Comment: Why are they "hanging out" in your office? Don't they have enough work to do? Is everything that needs to be done really getting done? And if so, why shouldn't they just hang out? And if everything is not getting done, why is that?

Comment: Not having much background info, I would assume that they hang out in your office because its the only place they can. Do they have a lounge to hang out in on their break? If not, then what do you expect them to do on their breaks? If they do but it is really inconvenient then come up with some other option for where they can hang out. I once worked at a large factory, it took 3 or 4 minutes to get to the break room, add in a restroom stop and using the vending machine, didn't leave much time to actually have a break during those 15 minute breaks.

Comment: I'd also add that your office might be the only place that "housekeeping" feels that "housekeeping" can hang out. The front office area/waiting room is probably less appropriate.

Comment: "If you have nothing to do, please don't do it here."

Comment: My Supervisor's Manager told me I could use their office if I needed to (but lately it is locked). Perhaps in past times, a Supervisor where you work said people could use the office? Or didn't care? Or, the office is new, and so there was no precedent? Seems like it would be good to discretely ask without antagonizing people.

Answer (score 29):

### Lock it

In all honesty, it's a perfectly polite way.  If you have an office, presumably you have a door that locks.  You want to get a key first, if you don't have one, but usually housekeeping has a key for cleaning... if not, leave wastebaskets outside your door and make arrangements for vacuuming and dusting.

Check in with you management on whether they need to get into the office, and get them a key if they need to get in.

### Consider the norms

If you are in an environment where people are regularly using your office while you're out - consider whether this fits the norms for your office.  There's various reasons why this happens - the culture may be informal, the office may be very short on space so that people are desperate.  Most people won't randomly walk into an office for the amusement factor - so they may have some purpose.

If you know of particular users of your office, ask them why they are using it -- "I'm just curious... why do you use my office when I'm not there?"  If the reason is dumb, they will probably stop.  If the reason is a good, they'll probably tell you.

### Address the problems caused

It is hard to say just "don't use my office"... but it's easier when you bring up points for concern... for example:

> I'm looking for help with keeping my office private.  I don't want to curtail business use that is necessary, but I'm not comfortable that my office becomes and open space when I go home for the evening.  Multiple times I've found left over cups and food in my office, and my things are moved around... it's frustrating to have to find my things and clean up a mess I didn't make when I come in in the morning... can folks find another place to hang out after work hours?"

That gives some clue as to why it's bugging you, and what has caused your frustration.  It makes your request sound reasonable.

Comment: thank you that was very help0ful because i feel as if they are taking my office as a hiding place to not do their work

Comment: +1 for locking up. Ask HR to install a deadbolt. You get a key, and they have a spare that they lock up so HR can get in if it's an emergency. I had the same problem in the past because I had a shelf of reference texts I kept in my office. Some people would get too cozy and be hanging around or taking phone calls when I got back from meetings.

Comment: It reads funny for you to say "housekeeping has a key" when the OP is a supervisor in Housekeeping : )

Answer (score 2):

If they are using your office as a lounge then need to put a stop to that.

It is not just an invasion of your space but they are not being productive if they are hanging out.

Put an inbox near the door or better yet if you have an external inbox then tell them just to use that.

> It appears that people may be using my office as a lounge when I am
>   not here.  There is no purpose to being in my office other than drop
>   of a message.  You can use the in box located xxx to drop of messages.

Answer (score 2):

There is a reason why people are issued offices, and it's not just for the ego boost. Partly it's so conversations (personal and on the phone) can be private, but also typically we might have confidential documents such as performance reviews and such like around when we're not.

I would say lock the door and have a slot installed for papers, if you think that's necessary. Management should be on your side on this.